# SQL Server Job with file system SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Using SQL Server 2016, I was able to run the package on another SQL Server 2016 but when I moved the SSIS package it failed with this error:

> 02/10/2021 16:20:31,ARGUS_DataEngine,Error,1,HORAE,ARGUS_DataEngine,Rename dhc File,,Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 13.0.4224.16 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  4:20:31 PM  Error: 2021-02-10 16:20:31.87     Code: 0xC001F02A     Source: ARGUS_DHC_Rename      Description: Cannot create a task from XML for task "Script Task Rename File" type "Microsoft.ScriptTask" due to error 0x80070057 "The parameter is incorrect.".  End Error  Error: 2021-02-10 16:20:31.88     Code: 0xC0010018     Source: Script Task Rename File      Description: Failed to load task "Script Task Rename File" type "". The contact information for this task is "".  End Error  Error: 2021-02-10 16:20:31.88     Code: 0xC0010026     Source: Script Task Rename File      Description: The task has failed to load. The contact information for this task is "".  End Error  Error: 2021-02-10 16:20:31.89     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Script Task Rename File      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  Error: 2021-02-10 16:20:31.89     Code: 0xC0010025     Source: ARGUS_DHC_Rename      Description: The package cannot execute because it contains tasks that failed to load.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  4:20:31 PM  Finished: 4:20:31 PM  Elapsed:  0.328 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.,00:00:00,0,0,,,,0

Comment: Using SQL 2016.  I was able to run the package on another SQL server 2016 but when I moved the SSIS package it failed with the above error.

Comment: Is SSIS installed on the server where it is not working?

Comment: Please provide more information: WHat do you mean by "moved the package"? Did you deploy it to another server? And what is the structure of your package? Are the same directories / files / whatever available on the server you tried to "move" the package to?

Answer (score 0):

Check the paths and the delyvalidation options in the package.
Are the new paths accessible from the new location of the package?
Is the account running the package granted this path?

It looks like you are running the package from the SQL Server Agent : NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT
Please explain more the situation, did you deployed the package to another server?

Also check the 32 bits option, from the agent options, a screenshot of this options is available here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/use-32bit-runtime-option-for-sql-agent/ba-p/387433